# Why does IntelliJ IDEA think my Boolean method is always inverted when it is not?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to using IntelliJ Idea and I have the following code:

```
private boolean verifyToken(TokenTypeEnum expectedTokenType, Token token) {
        return token != null &&
               token.getTokenType() == expectedTokenType &&
               token.getExpiryDate().isAfter(Instant.now());
}
```

Now IntelliJ-IDEA complains that this Boolean method is always inverted. But I specifically wrote the method so it returns a positive, I do not want to make a method isInvalidToken or something like that. I believe the point of this warning is actually to avoid negatives such as those.

What's more, if I actually let IntelliJ invert the method automatically, it makes the expression like this which is exactly NOT what I would want as it is much harder to reason about (even if I would rewrite the date comparison)

```
private boolean newNegativeMethod(TokenTypeEnum expectedTokenType, Token token) {
        return token == null ||
               token.getTokenType() != expectedTokenType ||
               !token.getExpiryDate().isAfter(Instant.now());
}
```

Why is it doing this? I can disable the warning of course, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Always inverted" means that in all places where the method is called, the ! operator is applied to the call expression. IntelliJ IDEA has no clue whether this is hard or easy to reason about from the semantic point of view; it just performs syntactic analysis. If you believe that inverting the method will make the code harder to understand, simply suppress the inspection for this method.

Comment: Ohhhh that's what it means. Yeah the method is used as a 'quick exit' in calling methods, similar to a guard like if (x == null) return. Oh well...

Comment: How do you suppress this inspection?  I don't see it in the IDE under the lightbulb menu, and can't find/guess the magic string for SuppressWarning.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")

Answer (score 1):

I have a use case where I need a view (android project) whenever an emergency condition is active.

I called this view EmergencyView:

```java
public class EmergencyView extends RelativeLayout {

   private boolean emergencyActive;

...

   public boolean isEmergencyActive() {
      return emergencyActive;
   }
}
```

In this use case, I get the `BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted` warning for my getter.  If I change the getter method's name to `isEmergency`, the warning goes away so there's a bit more being checked here than just the semantics of the code.

Initially, I went with `@SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")` to hide this warning, but ultimately I decided to change the name of my field to just be `emergency`.

The question remains whether "Emergency Active" or simply "Emergency" is the best way to describe the functional state of a View called `EmergencyView`, but I no longer get this warning nor do I have to suppress it.